# SharePoint online workbench not working using Edge

Tags: web-part, spfx

I'm about to develop a SharePoint modern web part but I cannot test my web part online using Edge (IE 11 works fine). I have deleted the gcb-serve-data folder and reinstalled the cert, still I get this message "Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp serve" is running in a web part project."

No build error. Working just fine using Edge locally, and IE11 works online but I don't want to use IE11!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known **bug** that already reported at [Testing SPFx on SharePoint Tenant (From Tutorials) does not work in Edge Browser](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/441)

**The workaround,**

- Continue to use IE 11 or Google Chrome!.
- Add the `localhost` URLs as **exceptions** as suggested in the above official link

Comment: Thanks! How/where exactly do I add localhost url-exceptions?

Comment: Welcome, please Check this https://itkb.csulb.edu/display/help/How+to+Add+Trusted+Sites+in+IE%2C+Chrome%2C+and+Firefox