# Not visible Sharepoint Custom web part on Edge browser

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have deployed my custom web part and able to see it in chrome, Firefox and IE, but not able to see it on Edge. Also, there is **no error** on console on Edge.

Do we need to make extra setting to make it visible in edge?

I found this 
[link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/251264/84746), here mentioned that **it is a existing and known bug**. 
So is it still not possible to make custom web part visible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do an internet search on "edge and sharepoint online compatibility problems" you'll find other people experience issues when using Edge.  The simplest solution is probably to use Internet Explorer, which I understand to be the most compatible with Sharepoint.  I think Chrome pretty well too, but not perfectly.

Lots of computers are supplied with Edge as the default browser; users just have to change their default browser to e.g. IE instead of Edge.  Also you'd want them to unpin Edge from their taskbar to prevent them from inadvertently using Edge.

That's my tuppence worth.